# Django rest framework extra serializer field with get and post

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to serialize a model and include extra field. I want use this serializer for list, detail and create views. In serialializer I use create, update, and get_field methods to customize logic.

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ("field", ...)
```

When I add new object everything is correct (I can validation custom field data), but when I get object, 'field' don't exists in response.

EDIT: I want set custom method on serializer class to get field. This is better logic solution for me then set custom method on model.

Why is it like that? Is exist better solution for this (I don't want use SerializerMethodField)?

Answer (score 4):

The field is not part of the model, due to that it is coming the error. You can make that field write_only=True.Suppose field is extra field.

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   field = serializers.CharField(write_only=true)

   class Meta:
      model = Example
      fields = ("field", ...)
```

or you can give the source value the field cross ponds to which field.

2. We can define the property method with that field name. You can include that field in the serializer as read only any data you can return for that

   ```
   class Example(model.MOdels):
     @property
     def field(self):
        return #whatever you want to return
   ```
3. you can use serilizermethod field .

   ```
    class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        field = serializers.serializerMethod()

        class Meta:
           model = Example
           fields = ("field", ...)
         def get_field(self, obj):
             return obj.data
   ```

Comment: When I add source attribute on field I must have custom method on model. I want use method on serializer class. That is better logic for me. Is that possible?

Comment: you have to give just source argument in that field in the string format.